# Identical If() and If yield different results

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

What is the difference in the two blocks of code below? I expected them to return the same result, but they don't.

In the case where xml.@Type = "null", I want PatientMetricTypeID (a nullable Integer) to end up being Nothing.

**Block #1: If()**

In this case, it ends up as 0. It looks like Nothing is being treated as an Integer and converted to 0. I can sort of see why this might happen but not fully... I would like to understand exactly how this works, and if there is a workaround.

```
    Dim PatientMetricTypeID As Integer? = If(xml.@Type = "null",
                                 Nothing,
                                 CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(PatientMetricTypes), xml.@Type), Integer))
```

**Block #2: If**

In this case, it ends up as Nothing -- expected behavior.

```
    Dim PatientMetricTypeID As Integer?

    If xml.@Type = "null" Then
        PatientMetricTypeID = Nothing
    Else
        PatientMetricTypeID = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(PatientMetricTypes), xml.@Type), Integer)
    End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `If` expression is of type `Integer`, not `Integer?`.

VB.Net's `Nothing` keyword is not equivalent to `null`; it's equivalent to C#'s  `default(T)`, where `T` is the type that the expression is used as.
To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> ## Nothing (Visual Basic)
>
> Represents the default value of any data type.

When you write `If(..., Nothing, SomeInteger)`, if `If` is typed as `Integer`, so `Nothing` turns into `0`.
To force the `If` expression to be typed as an `Integer?`, you can replace `Nothing` with `New Integer?()`.

For a more detailed explanation, [see my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nothing-vs-null.html).

Answer (score 1):

SLaks already explained the reason for this behaviour. This is another way to circumvent it:

```
... = If(xml.@Type = "null", DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?), ...)
```

About a year ago, I registered a bug report with Microsoft for this:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/496905/if-operator-not-returning-a-nullable-type

They consider adding a warning about this into the next release of the VB compiler.

Comment: Wow, they really took you seriously there. That's cool. :) +1 for the directcast fix.

Comment: Or, as I said, `New Integer?()`.

Answer (score 0):

My offer is to use `Integer?` inside `CType` instead of `Integer`

Comment: That won't work.  You cannot cast an enum to `Integer?` in one step.